# Qgis saving layers to geopackage

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, style, geopackage

I set up a geopackage to "hold" all the  reused resources so that it could be portable with custom styling (as I was led to believe)

Today I found out that dragging & dropping layers between instances does not copy the resources over, but just the references to the original; so an edit is applied to all instances..

Saving a qgis project to a geopackage doesn't seem to save the layers and styling into a geo package format either (which I was led to believe) but rather just stores the references to the original shape files?

How can one save a set of layers and styles in a portable way?